# Can I define a variable in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

So, this used to be possible in WPF & SL:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Name="MyDouble">1.2</x:Double>
</Grid.Resources>
```

But in WinRT-XAML it just underlines with:

> TypeConverter syntax error occurred while processing initialization string '1.2'

Anybody know the trick to do this?

**Solution**

Use x:Key not x:Name!

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="MyDouble">1.2</x:Double>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Those seem more like constants than variables to me. How do you bind or change the value of such if it's hard coded like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also get this:
"Type 'Double', and "Value Types" in general, cannot use x:Name"

If you switch from x:Name to x:Key - it works fine.